# How to retrieve object from query params in url in Angular 8

Tags: angular

I was wondering if there is a way how I can retrieve an array of objects from the queryParams in a url.
The objects that I want to retrieve should look like this.

```
events: [
 {
   locations: ['123456789', '987654321']
   period: {
     from: '2019-11-19',
     to: '2019-11-27'
   }
 },
 {
   locations: ['123456789']
   period: {
     from: '2018-01-23',
     to: '2018-01-25'
   }
 }
],
days: [0, 1, 2, 3],
groupBy: 'days',
extraSeries: ['visits']
```

So I was wondering how the queryparams in the url should look like and how I should retrieve them from the url. For example how do I get queryParam `events` which return the array of objects?

The reason why I need this is in the queryParams is because I want to be able to share a url with other users where the filter is set based on the queryParams.

Comment: First of all, you should know that you can reach some limitation in term or URL length (browser side or server side). You can have some details here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/812925/what-is-the-maximum-possible-length-of-a-query-string

Answer (score 3):

You can use `queryParams`

Look out this [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-b98yt3) it helps you

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';


 constructor( private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

 ngOnInit() {
     this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
        let event = params['events'];  
      });
  }
```

Comment: I tried this approach but events was undefined. Probably I used wrong queryParams in the url. The url that I used was like this `events[0][location]=921534361&events[0][period][from]=2019-11-19&events[0][period][to]=2019-11-25`

Comment: Check demo .. how we are using .. also check url

Comment: If I use this querystring `events[0][locations][0]=123456789&events[0][locations][1]=987654321&events[0][period][from]=2019-11-19&events[0][period][to]=2019-11-27&events[1][locations][0]=123456789&events[1][period][from]=2018-01-23&events[1][period][to]=2018-01-25` I'm not able to retrieve `params['events']` as it will be undefined because `params` contains keys like `events[0][locations][0]`. So I was wondering how I can transform the params to the object that I need.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't share the params as is. You can base64 encrypt and decrypt the params for sharing. Your example data encrypted:

`ZXZlbnRzOiBbDQogew0KICAgbG9jYXRpb25zOiBbJzEyMzQ1Njc4OScsICc5ODc2NTQzMjEnXQ0KICAgcGVyaW9kOiB7DQogICAgIGZyb206ICcyMDE5LTExLTE5JywNCiAgICAgdG86ICcyMDE5LTExLTI3Jw0KICAgfQ0KIH0sDQogew0KICAgbG9jYXRpb25zOiBbJzEyMzQ1Njc4OSddDQogICBwZXJpb2Q6IHsNCiAgICAgZnJvbTogJzIwMTgtMDEtMjMnLA0KICAgICB0bzogJzIwMTgtMDEtMjUnDQogICB9DQogfQ0KXSwNCmRheXM6IFswLCAxLCAyLCAzXSwNCmdyb3VwQnk6ICdkYXlzJywNCmV4dHJhU2VyaWVzOiBbJ3Zpc2l0cydd`

The encrypted data is not shorter, but it has url-friendly characters

Answer (score -1):

It may help to you try below code:

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';


constructor( private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

ngOnInit() {
  this.route.queryParams.subscribe(
  params => {
    let event = params['events'];  
  });
}
```

Comment: Dont copy paste as it is from other answers.. Modify it and explain in better way :)

Comment: I had tried and its work for me so I put this answer.